# Why does a JPA @PreUpdate-annotated method get called during a query?

Tags: jpa

I have a named query that returns a `Collection` of entities.

These entities have a `@PreUpdate`-annotated method on them.  This method is invoked during `query.getResultList()`.  Because of this, the entity is changed within the persistence context, which means that upon transaction commit, the entity is written back to the database.

Why is this?  The JPA 2.0 specification does not mention explicitly that `@PreUpdate` should be called by query execution.

Comment: I see this behavior, incidentally, in EclipseLink 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461 in case it is a severe bug in that implementation only.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem, but with Hibernate. So it seems like it's not an implementation issue but an expected behavior. Somehow this seems to be due to some automated flushing induced by JTA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The specification says:

> The PreUpdate and PostUpdate callbacks occur before and after the
>   database update operations to entity data respectively. These database
>   operations may occur at the time the entity state is updated or they
>   may occur at the time state is flushed to the database (which may be
>   at the end of the transaction).

In this case calling `query.getResultList()` triggers a `em.flush()` so that the query can include changed from current EntityManager session. `em.flush()` pushes all the changes to the database (makes all UPDATE,INSERT calls). Before `UPDATE` is sent via JDBC `@PreUpdate` corresponding hooks are called.

Comment: however, this is only called when there are changes available. This question really made me question if PostUpdate was any good at all...

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem OP had, because it sounded like the EntityManager would get flushed everytime the query is called. But that's not the case. @PostUpdate methods are only called when there is actual changed being done to the Database as far as I can tell. If you made a change with the EntityManager that is not yet flushed to the DB query.getResultList will trigger the flush to the DB which is the behaviour one should expect.

Comment: In my case, I do have both @PostLoad and @PreUpdate that change the same field, so upon query.getResultList(), `@PostLoad` gets called, updates the field, method returns and triggers both flush and `@PreUpdate`? Anyway, my use case is to encode a field before storing to the DB and decoding it when reading. It seems like entity listeners are useless here.

Comment: @hareluya86 even my use case is same, seems like cannot do `PrePersist` and `PostLoad`. Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

This is just my comment from rzymek's answer with some follow up code:

I tried to reproduce the problem OP had, because it sounded like the EntityManager would get flushed everytime the query is called. But that's not the case. @PostUpdate methods are only called when there is actual changed being done to the Database as far as I can tell. If you made a change with the EntityManager that is not yet flushed to the DB query.getResultList will trigger the flush to the DB which is the behaviour one should expect.

```
        Place valinorDb = em.find(Place.class, valinorId);
        // this should not trigger an PostUpdate and doesn't
        // TODO: unit-testify this
        em.merge(valinorDb);

        valinorDb.setName("Valinor123");
        valinorDb.setName("Valinor");
        // this shouldn't trigger an PostUpdate because the Data is the same as in the beginning and doesn't
        em.merge(valinorDb);

        {
            // this is done to test the behaviour of PostUpdate because of
            // this:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097485/why-does-a-jpa-preupdate-annotated-method-get-called-during-a-query
            //
            // this was tested by hand, but should maybe changed into a unit
            // test? PostUpdate will only get called when there is an actual
            // change present (at least for Hibernate & EclipseLink) so we
            // should be fine
            // to use PostUpdate for automatically updating our index

            // this doesn't trigger a flush as well as the merge didn't even trigger one
            Place place = (Place) em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Place a")
                    .getResultList().get(0);

            Sorcerer newSorcerer = new Sorcerer();
            newSorcerer.setName("Odalbort the Unknown");

            place.getSorcerers().add(newSorcerer);

            //this WILL trigger an PostUpdate as the underlying data actually has changed.
            place = (Place) em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Place a")
                    .getResultList().get(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case JPA Event Listener ([@EntityListeners](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/entitylisteners)) calls `query.getResultList()` in its logic (to do some validation) and in effect goes into
neverending loop that calls the same listener once again and again and in the end got `StackOverflowError`. I used `flush-mode` = `COMMIT` to avoid flush on query like below. Maybe for someone it will be helpful.

```
List l = entityManager.createQuery(query)
    /**
    * to NOT do em.flush() on query that trigger 
    * @PreUpdate JPA listener 
    */
    .setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT)
    .getResultList();
```