# @PreUpdate triggered on select

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.0, stack-overflow

I have model class with `preUpdate()` method, which is annotated with @PreUpdate.
This method calls my method `deleteCache()`:

```
public void deleteCache() {
    final List<Model> models = Model.findAll();
    for (final Model model : models) {
        Cache.remove(model.id);
    }
}
```

My `Model.findAll()` implementation:

```
public static List<Model> findAll() {
    Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("SELECT o FROM Model o");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

When I trigger Model.save() my preUpdate method is called and it calls deleteCache, but when the `return query.getResultList()` is reached the preUpdate method is called again and so I get the StackoverflowException.

Can anyone explain to me why the preUpdate method is called even there is no change to model? Is there something wrong with the code? Thanks.

EDIT:
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097485/why-does-a-jpa-preupdate-annotated-method-get-called-during-a-query) post, so em.flush() is called. But there are no UPDATE, INSERT calls.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend against interacting with JPA inside of the JPA-listener callbacks. In my experience it is a road with lots of nasty and unexpected behaviour (and lots of hours of debugging).